# How is this boolean value being set

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have come across the following code and don't understand it.

```
Dim bTemp as boolean = False
Dim License as integer = 2066350014
bTemp = aAreaLicence(1) And License
```

If `aAreaLicence(1) = 64` then the boolean is set to false

If `aAreaLicence(1) = 16` then the boolean is set to true

I have no idea what is happening here, can someone explain it please?

Comment: What is aAreaLicence?

Comment: Did you copy / paste the code because  License <> Licences?

Comment: aAreaLicence is an array. no diodnt copy and paste. sorry about that will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)

**And Operator**

*Performs a logical conjunction on two Boolean expressions, or a bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions*.

So in your case you are having a bitwise conjunction.

```
64 And 2066350014
```

evaluates to `0` which is `False` when converted to a Boolean value because it is Zero

```
16 And 2066350014
```

evaluates to `16` which is `True` when converted to a Boolean value because it is Non-Zero

Answer (score 4):

Numbers Licences and aAreaLicence(1) are converted to binary and then operation "and" is executed on every bit. So:

```
2066350014 (10) = 1111011001010011111111110111110 (2)
        64 (10) = 0000000000000000000000001000000 (2)
        16 (10) = 0000000000000000000000000010000 (2)
```

If we execute "and" operation:

```
1111011001010011111111110111110 
And
0000000000000000000000001000000 
=
0000000000000000000000000000000 - that means 2066350014 And 64 = false

1111011001010011111111110111110
And
0000000000000000000000000010000
=
0000000000000000000000000010000 - that means 2066350014 And 16 = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal to Binary:

> 2066350014 = 1111011001010011111111110111110
>
> 64 = 1000000
>
> 16 = 10000

Then use Boolean algebra:

```
bTemp = aAreaLicence(1) And Licences = 64 AND 2066350014 = 0  = false

bTemp = aAreaLicence(1) And Licences = 16 AND 2066350014 = 16 = true
```